# HTML select fields using tep_draw in osCommerce

Tags: php, html, forms, select, oscommerce

I am trying to create a form in osCommerce and trying to stick with the required tep_draw.

My input fields and radio buttons work but I am having problems with the select field. I know the country input field is wrong but don't know the correct tep_draw_select option.

This is what I'm trying now:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td class="fieldKey"><div class="crosspiece95"></div><?php echo ENTRY_ADDRESS; ?></td>
  <td class="fieldValue" width="100%"><?php echo tep_draw_input_field('address', '', 'class="input"'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="fieldKey"><?php echo ENTRY_CITY; ?></td>
  <td class="fieldValue"><?php echo tep_draw_input_field('city', '', 'class="input"'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="fieldKey"><?php echo ENTRY_STATE; ?></td>
  <td class="fieldValue"><?php echo tep_draw_input_field('state', '', 'class="input"'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="fieldKey"><?php echo ENTRY_ZIP; ?></td>
  <td class="fieldValue"><?php echo tep_draw_input_field('zip', '', 'class="input"'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="fieldKey"><?php echo ENTRY_COUNTRY; ?></td>
  <td class="fieldValue"><?php echo tep_draw_input_field('country', '', 'class="input"'); ?>
    <option value="">Country...</option>
    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="etc">ETC</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To output a `<select>` input field on your form, you can use the `tep_draw_pull_down_menu` function found in **includes/functions/html_output.php**

You will need to pass an associative array to the method with id and text values.

A sample array and call to the method would be like this:

```
$pocket_monsters = array(
  array('id' => '1', 'text' => 'Squirtle'),
  array('id' => '2', 'text' => 'Charmander'),
  array('id' => '3', 'text' => 'Bulbasaur'),
);

echo tep_draw_pull_down_menu('pocket_monsters', $pocket_monsters);
```

Or, if you want to display a `<select>` input field with all the countries that have been set up in the database, use the `tep_get_country_list` method. It's [in the same file](https://github.com/oscommerce/oscommerce2/blob/master/catalog/includes/functions/html_output.php#L327), and looks like this:

```
function tep_get_country_list($name, $selected = '', $parameters = '') {
  $countries_array = array(array('id' => '', 'text' => PULL_DOWN_DEFAULT));
  $countries = tep_get_countries();

  for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($countries); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $countries_array[] = array('id' => $countries[$i]['countries_id'], 
      'text' => $countries[$i]['countries_name']);
  }

  return tep_draw_pull_down_menu($name, $countries_array, $selected, $parameters);
}
```